# Skiing demo plate vs no demo plate

Tags: skiing, ski-bindings

I have a pair of salomon rocker 2s with z12 bindings on a demo plate. Would it be advantageous for my skiing performance to remove the demo plate and have the bindings directly on the skis? I normally hang out on big mountain shoots and dense tree runs.

Answer (score 3):

If you know exactly where your bindings need to be fixed then you don't need the demo plate, and fixing directly to the ski gives a more rigid connection between boot and ski.

A demo plate is only really useful if you need adjustment.